# ItemTpl onclick function call extjs 6

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, extjs6

how do i call a onclick function on dataview,

```
itemTpl: [
'<a onClick="this.getViewController().somefunction({id},{code});" href="#">{code}</a><br/>',
]
```

and in viewController

```
somefunction: function(){
// some logic
}
```

gives the error of

> this.getViewController() is not a function

**NOTE: that i don't wan't to do `MyApp.app.getController()` because i have many ViewControllers and i cannot put all my logic to a centeral contoller**

Comment: Are you using ext6 or sencha touch? If the former, is it the modern or classic toolkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to bind a click function in `itemTpl`, you need to specify functions accessible in the template like this:

```
// Save 'this' scope to me variable for use in XTemplate scope
var me = this;

// ...

itemTpl: [
    '<a onClick="this.someFunction();" href="#">{code}</a><br/>',
    // Defining funtions accessible in the XTemplate
    {
        someFunction: function() {
            // Use 'me' here, because 'this' is XTemplate
            me.getViewController().someFunction();
        }
    }
]
```

But if at all possible, I would use click listener on the item instead, like so:

```
// Save 'this' scope to me variable for use in the item scope
var me = this;

// ...

itemConfig: {
    listeners: {
        click: function() {
            // Use 'me' here, because 'this' is the item
            me.getViewController().someFunction();
        }
    }
}
```

I usually work in ExtJS 4 and got this just from the ExtJS 6 [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/modern/Ext.dataview.DataView.html), so please excuse any mistakes I made and correct me, so that I can edit the answer.

Comment: The problem with the click listeners is that i cannot pass params as they are dynamic
Checking the first approach...

Comment: NO not working, it was looking good, that why i upvoted but not working, Giving the same error this.somefunction is not a function

Comment: You mean the click listener? In my example code there are comments regarding not using `this` directly in the listener. Díd you use a substitute variable? Could you provide a working fiddle with the minimal working code with your problem?

Comment: In the first code sample the correct code is `'<a onClick="me.someFunction();" href="#">{code}</a><br/>', ...`

Comment: @DevN No, it isn't. `me` is not defined in the template code, so the proposed code would end with an exception.